# Angular 2 Get Values from Object

Tags: angular, object

I am trying to get value from a json url,
i got this result:
[Console Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVovT.png)

How can i extract each item from this object (closePrice, price,updateTime)

this my code:

```
GoldData:any;

GetGoldFromJson() {
  this.http.get('http://live.alsayg.com/api/v1/gold')
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
    this.GoldData=data,
   console.log(this.GoldData);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Just by typing `this.GolData.variableThatINeedToUse`?

Comment: Yes, but i can't read the value outside the function GetGoldFromJson(). i got this error : Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Comment: Maybe the problem is, that the code you are using outside of the function is called before the http request returns. Make sure to use the variable only after it has been set or use a default value.

Comment: http.Get perform an asynchronous request, you need to use `then()` for using GoldData outside subscribe

Comment: How can i use then() in this code ? i am new in angular 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this (in your service class):

```
GetGoldFromJson() {
  return this.http.get('http://live.alsayg.com/api/v1/gold')
  .map(res => res.json())
}
```

and consume with (in your component, just inject the above service in the constructor of your component):

```
GoldData:any;
getGold() {
   service.GetGoldFromJson().subscribe(
    data => {
    this.GoldData=data,
   console.log(this.GoldData);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: What about if you only need specific filed(s) from the response?

Answer (score 1):

This is an async operation, so as per comments the view is rendered before data has been retrieved, therefore the error is thrown. You can solve this in a couple of ways.

Initialize your object, so that it won't be undefined.

```
GoldData:any = {}
```

Use `*ngIf`, which will prevent the part of of the view to be rendered until there is  values in `GoldData`:

```
<div *ngIf="GoldData">
   {{GoldData.yourProperty}}
</div>
```

or **[safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator)**:

```
{{GoldData?.yourProperty}}
```